# ExpressJS get file from FormData

Tags: ajax, node.js, file, express, multipartform-data

I am a new bee to `ExpressJS`, 
I want to upload a `file` and some `data` from `javascript`, using `AJAX post` as  `FormData object`, to express js `routes`, to save the file in server. I am able to post from front end, but not able to retrieve data from server side.

Following is the code snippet I tried:

AJAX post from client side code snippet:

```
var files = [];
    $('#upload').on('change',function(){
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file_uplaoded',$('#upload')[0].files[0]);
        form_data.append('name1',"10000900055");
        form_data.append('name2',"10000900044");
        form_data.append('name3',"10000900033");
        form_data.append('name4',"10000900022");
        form_data.append('name5',"10000900011");
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ulploadfile',
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert('success');
            }
            // dataType: 'json',
            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).done(function(data) {
            // alert('success1');
        });
    });
```

Server side code snippet:

```
router.post('/ulploadfile', function(req, res, next) {
    var body = '';
    try {
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            var post = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(post);
            res.send("UPLOADING FILE RESPONSE");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send("UPLOADING FILE RESPONSE ERRPR");
    } finally {
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
OUT PUT SCREENSHOT
[image: Output sceenshot]

So I would like to know how retrieve the data posted from the request object in backend. I would like to do it without using any other packages.

Many Many Thanks for the help & suggestions.

Comment: Got it resolved by https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good module for files (multipart data) in POST requests, called [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

You may add there validation functions, destination, different storages...
There is even addon [multer-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) for that, to use as a storage.

```js
router.post('/ulploadfile', upload.single('file_uplaoded'), function(req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `file_uplaoded` file 
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```