# Upload raw file with vue.js, node.js and express.js

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

Please tell me how I can upload a file to express.js server witch use `bodyparser.raw()`

- client side

```html
<input type='file' @change='onFilePicked' />
```

```js
// ...
onFilePicked(file) {
  const url = 'upload/api/url';
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('upload', file);
  fd.append('key', 'somestring');
  axios.post(url,fd).then( res => { console.log(res); }, err => { console.log(err); });
}
// ...
```

- server side

```js
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.raw());

app.post('upload/api/url', (res, req) => {
  console.log(req.req.key); //undefined
  console.log(req.req.upload); //undefined

  res.res.status(500).send("WIP");
});
```

I have to use `bodyparser.raw()`. Maybe can I pul `form data` as value into json object?

I can not read file content inside `app.post('upload/api/url', ... );`.

Comment: I think req.req.key is a typo? Try to  `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: `req` object is given as function param and it is `ServerResponse` type. `req.req` is a field of `req` and it is `IncomingMessage` type. So `req.req` in my code is equal to `ServerResponse.req` ...

Comment: `conosle.log(req.body)` => `udefined` /  `conosle.log(req.req.body)` => `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40411508/9018487
and: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

- client side

```js
// ...
onFilePicked(file) {
  const url = 'upload/api/url';
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('upload', file);
  fd.append('key', 'somestring');
  axios.post(url,fd, {
    headers: {
      ...
      'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  .then( res => { console.log(res); }, err => {console.log(err); });
}
// ...
```

- server side

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({dest: "/data/"});

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.raw());

app.post('upload/api/url', multer.single('upload'), (res, req) => {
  console.log(req.req.file);
/*
{
  fieldname: 'upload',
  originalname: 'somefile.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  destination: 'tmp/',
  filename: '564968d9611fa809e4b32233854f12aa',
  path: 'data/564968d9611fa809e4b32233854f12aa',
  size: 93038
}
*/

  // TODO:
  // 1. Open and read file req.req.file.path to local variable
  // 2. Remove file req.req.file.path
  // 3. Do something with data from file

  res.res.status(500).send("WIP");
});
```